# How to abort file upload in java server?

Tags: java

Basically I have a client-side File upload which could be used for uploading files to server, and in my server-side I have limited file size using `MultipartConfig` to 5MB and if the file has exceeded the limit I need to abort the uploading process.

Server-Side:

```
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp", fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024, 
maxFileSize=1024*1024*5, maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5)


 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;
    try{
        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "D:\\");
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    out.print("Successfully Uploaded");
}
```

FYI: I have my `@MultipartConfig` out of my class

As you can see I have a `try and catch` which if the file limit has exceeded throws an exception saying about the file exceed exception, Here I need to abort the uploading process, and send a simple error to client that limit has exceeded.

Comment: So? Use the response to send an suitable status code and anything else you want.

Comment: `sendError` is a shortcut method to do that.

Comment: Okay I just found that for my condition `httpError 409` is a suitable error and I tried putting `response.sendError(response.SC_CONFLICT, "File limit has exceeded");` in my `catch` But that didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

You can use httpget.abort() to abort/cancel the request.

```
public class ClientAbortMethod {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get");

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                // Do not feel like reading the response body
                // Call abort on the request object
                httpget.abort();
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

[Refer this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAbortMethod.java)